# Naming coordinates in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write out the coordinates of a 3d object, but I'm not sure how to list it.

so far I have:

```
class threed:
    def __init__(self,length,width,height):
        self.h =height
        self.l = length
        self.w = width
        self.f=0
        self.lwh = (length,width,height)

for i in range(1,3):
      for j in range(1,3):
           for k in range(1,3):
                coordinates=threed(i,j,k)
```

The problem is my function rewrites the variable coordinates each time so that I can't ever access coordinate (1,1,1) for example.

Note the above is for a 2x2x2 object.

How do I write it efficiently so that I can reference any coordinate as I need?

Comment: Is the second `self.h` supposed to be `self.w`? And do you mean you want a multidimensional array? If it's in a multidimensional array, why even bother, since you can just create a new class instance based on the position you would have fetched it in in the array? If it's not a multidimensional array, what are you trying to do?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Other than the typo @minitech mentions, there's nothing wrong with your `threed` class other than the fact that it doesn't really do anything. Your loops don't accomplish much, but it's not clear what you're aiming for.

Comment: Sorry, yea the self.h for the second one should be self.w. @Blcknght I'm trying to write a program that fills a container, so the reason I need a class is basically to reference `.f` and see if it's empty or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
[threed(*x) for x in itertools.product(range(1, 3), range(1,3), range(1,3))]
```

to have each object. You may also use 3 `for` loops as well:

```
[threed(x, y, z) for x in range(1, 3) for y in range(1,3) for z in range(1,3)]
```

---

Adding the `__repr__` method to your class, you can see more easily the result.

```
def __repr__(self):
    return 'threed' + repr(self.lwh)
```

So the output of the first code will be:

```
[threed(1, 1, 1), threed(1, 1, 2), threed(1, 2, 1), threed(1, 2, 2), 
 threed(2, 1, 1), threed(2, 1, 2), threed(2, 2, 1), threed(2, 2, 2)]
```

---

To allow `threed` objects to be compared, you can add a `__eq__` method:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.lwh == other.lwh
```

Comment: is there a way that I can reference the elements of that list by referencing the coordinates, for example if I type threed(1,1,1) in that list, it will say False

Comment: @Chowza That's because you haven't wrote a method to make your `threed` objects comparable.

Comment: How would I write a method to make it comparable?

Comment: @Chowza read the last part of the answer I just wrote. Be sure to add the `return` I forgot when writing

Answer (score 1):

After `coordinates=threed(i,j,k)` you can add coordinates to a dictionary, for efficient access later.

Something like:

```
obj3d = dict()
for i in range(1,3):
      for j in range(1,3):
           for k in range(1,3):
                key = (i, j, k)
                obj3d[key] = threed(*key)
```

Then you have a `obj3d` dictionary, and can do:

```
  any_threed = obj3d[(1,1,1)]
```

Of course, you can use `itertools` etc. to tidy up the way you generate the coordinates, but I focused this answer on getting an efficient method of accessing the coordinates later.